How to find automate holding down a key
Let's say I want to automate a key hold h for a specific duration, say 10 seconds.
My first thought was AutoHotKey, and I tried it.
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
*s::
{
    Send "{h down}" 
    Sleep 10000
    Send "{h up}" 
}

it works. but it taps the h, not holding it. And I look at the AutoHotKey forum, no one has any idea how to make it automatic, the best solution is to hold down the trigger, which defeat the purpose.
Then I went to PyAutoGUI, tried make a simple solution like
import pyautogui
import time


pyautogui.keyDown('h')
time.sleep(10)
pyautogui.keyUp('h')

Somehow it only taps the h, not holding it down.
I tried AutoHotKey and PyAutoGUI, and they only can tap the key, not holding it.
ANSWERED: it does hold the key, but it won't repeat the keypress in word processors such as notedpad like hhhhhhhh, because that's actually the keyboard's driver feature.

how do you know that it doesn't hold it? Where do you want to hold h? In what program you need it? Maybe problem is this program, not AutoHotKey and PyAutoGUI, maybe it doesn't need to hold it but press it again and again.

Well I want it to hold, not repeated press. And I want it to work whatever the situation. If I'm on notepad it'll make 'hhhhh'. If I'm in a game (if the key is 'w') the character would walk for 10 seconds. The h is just a simple example case, in which it's really hard for me to find a simple solution that work as intended. I know it doesn't hold it because I tested it, in notepad, in browser, it just type 'h' and stopped, doesn't matter how much time I put.

you should add it in question - it can be useful to understand it. And sometimes it doesn't have to work - some programs may use different method to get keys - ie. some games. And as I remember in system you can change if key will be repeated when you hold it - so some programs may change it.

In the case of notepad, the behavior of the repeating character is triggered by the keyboard repeat feature of Windows (importantly: not notepad), which is a behavior that is only triggered for physical keyboards, rather than simulated inputs. So, the key state is technically down, but the key repeat doesn't trigger. However, this should still work while holding down the button in a program (like a video game) that is explicitly looking for the button state.

It is standard behavior in AHK.
See Repeating or Holding Down a Key
To simulate repeated keypresses as with a real keyboard you have to use loops or timers.
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
#SingleInstance force

settimer, fire, 50
settimer, fire, off

F2::
    send h
    sleep 500
    settimer, fire, on
    keywait, F2
    settimer, fire, off
return

fire:
    send h
return


There might be 2 problems:
1. It's programmed this way

The game engine your game was made in might not care about getting a
hold down event. Usually they check if the key is in down state.

2. There is a virtual keyboard preventation system

This more unlikely but may explain why it doesn't hold down.

Specifying the context for the hold down action will help us look through what is the problem and recreate it.
